# "!= nor <>" doesn't work when selecting data with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table employee:
[image]

And what I want to select is list of employees who do not have a designated chief who works in the same department (employee #24 have chief from another department and some ppl doesn't have chief at all)

So here is the question: 
Why this works:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    employee a
WHERE
    a.cheif_id NOT IN (SELECT 
            cheif_id
        FROM
            employee b
        WHERE
            b.dep_id = a.dep_id
                AND b.id = a.cheif_id);
```

but this does not:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    employee a
WHERE
    a.cheif_id <> (SELECT 
            cheif_id
        FROM
            employee b
        WHERE
            b.dep_id = a.dep_id
                AND b.id = a.cheif_id);
```

In addition if we want to select employees who Do have a designated chief who works in the same department '=' and 'in ()' works.

Sorry for cheif mistake.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there are multiple data in your Subquery,you can't use `<>`,you can use `NOT IN`

I think you can use `JOIN` instead of `subquery`

```
SELECT e1.name chiefname,e2.*
FROM employee e1
INNER JOIN e2 
ON  e1.dep_id = e2.dep_id AND e1.id = e2.cheif_id
```

Comment: Yeah your right `select * from (select 11 as a , 11 as b
union 
select 21 as a , 22 as b
union 
select 31 as a , null as b
) as Table2  where b <> (select 22,11);` but this is ok:        `select * from (select 11 as a , 11 as b
union 
select 21 as a , 22 as b
union 
select 31 as a , null as b
) as Table2  where b <> (select 11);`